NPM pre- and postinstall scripts of my lib is suddenly running on install into the project
The odd thing is that it appeared "suddenly" for everyone on the team, so I exclude the reason being local changes.
We have a component-lib, which has a preinstall and a postinstall script. Both script rely on git sub-modules within the component lib, and are needed for dev env set up of the lib. Now since yesterday both the preinstall and postinstall of the component-lib are executed when installed into a project.
Since this is happening to multiple projects on multiple machines and only for tags which are created since yesterday our guess is that something is different when building.
Here is the package.json from the component lib:
    "postinstall": "bash scripts/pipelines/npmrc/reset_npmrc.sh && husky install && npx browserslist@latest --update-db",
    "preinstall": "npm run sub-module-update && bash scripts/pipelines/npmrc/prepare_npmrc.sh",

Here is the error message I receive when running an npm i @mylib/component-library-react:
npm i @mylib/component-library-react@3.8.22
npm error code 127
npm error path /home/snakepy/Desktop/work/portal/frontend2.0/node_modules/@mylib/component-library-react
npm error command failed
npm error command sh -c npm run sub-module-update && bash scripts/pipelines/npmrc/prepare_npmrc.sh
npm error > @mylib/component-library-react@3.8.22 sub-module-update
npm error > git submodule update --remote --init --recursive
npm error bash: scripts/pipelines/npmrc/prepare_npmrc.sh: No such file or directory
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/snakepy/.npm/_logs/2024-08-15T10_50_12_774Z-debug-0.log

So I do understand the error message, it is trying to execute the preinstall of the @mylib/component-library-react, but why and how can I revert back?
A quick fix, is basically to remove the scripts from the component-lib's package.json
Edit:
I notice that the tags since yesterady add "hasInstallScript": true to the package-lock.json in a project where I install the lib.
  "node_modules/@mylib/component-library-react": {
      "version": "3.8.22",
      "resolved": "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/_id/packages/npm/@mylib/component-library-react/-/@mylib/component-library-react-3.8.22.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-403sNqVBXom/xdkBtty2tSM0loU=",
      "hasInstallScript": true,
    ...
    }


